# Remove extra spaces if more than one space through vb.net Oracle query

Tags: vb.net, winforms, oracle

Just looking for another way to remove any excess spaces(>1) throughout a query.  I'm taking information for my Oracle query from an Excel spreadsheet so there's bound to be some excess zeroes due to user error and whatnot so that when I'm taking the information from the excel it will have 2 sometimes 3 extra spaces after some values so we won't get any records returned from Oracle when we query it through the application.  I have tried Trim(ds.Tables.Item(0).Rows.Item(k).Item(i).ToString.ToUpper) but this isn't removing the extra spaces in some of the values.  Is there some SQL statement I don't know of or perhaps another reason why Trim isn't working?

Edit:  Was writing replace function incorrectly.

```
Original: string.Replace("  ", " ")
New: string = string.replace("  ", " ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.Replace(" ", String.Empty)` instead.    `Trim` only removes leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: Hi Douglas, I have tried this as well and am not having luck with this.  I can prove that it is seeing the two spaces in the cell(.contains("  ")) but is not replacing the two spaces for one.  I've tried having it replace it with one space and even tried what you suggested and put it to an empty string and it looks like it's not changing the string at all

Comment: Are you sure it's a space and not some other character?

Comment: What else could it be?  I can check and verify that it has 2 spaces in it, all the other values I'm using in my query that only have one space aren't going into the if statement i'm using to check the number of spaces

Answer (score 0):

On the Oracle side, you can use the [`REGEXP_REPLACE` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions137.htm), but you need to apply it to each column you want to remove the extra spaces from:

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_REPLACE(myCol1, ' {2,}', ' ') AS myCleanCol1,
  REGEXP_REPLACE(myCol2, ' {2,}', ' ') AS myCleanCol2,
FROM myTable
```

The example here looks for all occurrences of two or more spaces (that's the second parameter) and replaces them with a single space (the third parameter).

Answer (score 0):

You can use REGEXP_REPLACE

Could be something like this:

```
regexp_replace(your_column, '\s{2,}', '')
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/18385)